# stop animation in the scrollView content offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I want to set the content offset of the scroll view **WITHOUT ANIMATION**.This is the simple code that I have applied but its not working:

```
[_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*currentPage, 0) animated:NO];
```

After performing my task when I am going back to my scroll view, its index resets to 0 and then to my current index. That is fine. But why is the scrolling animation happening when I have set the animation to NO.

Please help.

Comment: I believe another code is triggering the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
_scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*currentPage, 0);
```

Comment: In that case it's not to do with your line of code setting the content offset. From  your description it sounds like something else (e.g. a method in viewWillAppear of your hosting view controller) is manipulating the scroll view. Without seeing more code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

[ UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width*currentPage, 0) animated:NO];
    }];

Answer (score 0):

try below to stop animation:

```
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
    [CATransaction commit];
```